# Prolog merge two lists

Tags: list, recursion, merge, prolog

I need to merge two lists in Prolog. On input should be predicate `merge/3`.

[image: Visual Hint]

Should work like this:

```
?- merge([6,4,b,8], [5,b,s,6], X).
X = [6, 4, b, 8, 5, s].
```

What I have tried:

```
%rules
merge(A, B, X):- 
    merge(A, B, B, X).

merge([], X, _, X).
merge([Head|L1], [Head|L2], Tmp, [Head|X]) :-
    merge(L1, L2, Tmp, X),
    !.
merge(L1, [_|L2], Tmp, X) :-
    merge(L1, L2, Tmp, X),
    !.
merge([A|L1], [], Tmp, [A|X]) :-
    merge(L1, Tmp, Tmp, X),
    !.
```

What I get:

```
?- merge([1,2,a,3], [5,d,a,1], X).
X = [1, 2, a, 3, 5, d, a, 1].
```

What I expect:

```
?- merge([1,2,a,3], [5,d,a,1], X).
X = [1, 2, a, 3, 5, d].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by rewriting built-in predicates ! e.g :

```
my_append([], R, R) .
my_append([H|T], R1, [H|R2]) :-
    my_append(T, R1, R2).


my_member(H, [H|_]).
my_member(H, [_|T]) :-
    my_member(H, T).
```

So, I can say that merging L with an empty list gives this list L

```
merge(L, [], L).
```

Now, to merge two lists, I look at the first element of the second list.

If it is in the first list, I ignore it and I merge the first list, with the rest of the second.

If not, I add this first element at the end of the first list and I merge the new first list with the rest of the second.

I must say that it's not very efficient !!

```
merge(L, [H| T], R) :-
    (   my_member(H, L)
    ->  merge(L, T, R)
    ;   my_append(L, [H], L1),
        merge(L1, T, R)).
```

Comment: __Thanks__, it works exactly as it should. Now I will try to understand how.)

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the elements does not somehow depend on the order of the two input lists, this is an idiomatic Prolog solution:

```
?- append([6,4,b,8], [5,b,s,6], A), sort(A, B).
A = [6, 4, b, 8, 5, b, s, 6],
B = [4, 5, 6, 8, b, s].
```

If the order is important, you need to explain how exactly.

And some comments on the code you show. The names that you have chosen for your predicates: both "join" and "merge" have well-established meanings *different* from what you seem to be attempting to achieve ("join" as in relational databases, "merge" as in "merge two ordered lists"). What you are doing is rather a ["union"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#union/3) (and by the way, click on this link and read the code!).

Also, it is almost always a mistake (not an error, but a mistake) to have a cut as the last subgoal of a clause body. Having multiple clauses to a predicate that are not obviously mutually exclusive (as the last 3 of the 4 clauses to your `merge/4`) is commonly a design flaw (not a mistake).

Comment: Thank you alot, but i have to do this with recursion without using built-in predicates. I have a tasks like this. https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/1 It would be much pleasure, if someone could explain me how to do this. So i must get exact answer X = [6, 4, b, 8, 5, s].

Comment: @InQuirer In addition to "what I need" and "what I have tried", your question should at least have the following: "what I get", and "what exactly is my problem with understanding why I don't get what I expect". You should also explicitly define how the order of elements of the two input lists influences the order of elements of the result.

Comment: @InQuirer And I understand that you cannot tell your professor or instructor that, but "solve this using recursion without using built-in predicates" is so silly that it isn't even funny.... I am sorry for you :(